# Expandable hash function

Tags: hash, implementation

I have been studying a cryptosystem using Mersenne primes. More specifically, [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/481.pdf).

I have implemented this cryptosystem in Python, but I am missing the key encapsulation system.

On page 12, they refer to something known as an "expandable hash function". It should take as input a $\lambda$-bit string and output a uniformly random $n$-bit string ($\lambda<<n$) of Hamming weight $h$. This weight $h$ is already determined (actually $h=\lambda$).

I am kind of new to this stuff. Is there a way to implement this hash function in Python?

Comment: @kelalaka but what about the Hamming weight?

Comment: Hmm, would this just be $H'(m)\leftarrow_\$ S(\text{1}^h\parallel\text{0}^\left(n-h\right))$? All you gotta do is find a way to use $H$ to uniformly randomly select a permutation of `'1' * h + '0' * (n-h)`. Have you got any candidates for expandable hash functions currently? ([This question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/32157/8287) may prove informative or helpful)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude no, I have not. How would you implement it in python?

Comment: I was too dumb to properly understand [or implement](https://replit.com/@squeegily/sponjge) it, but it appears that [this paper](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs276/fa20/notes/Luby_Rackoff_paper.pdf) provides a general method for doing so (or, at least, constructing a function that constructs functions that do so)

Comment: While I haven't yet figured out the permutation generator, It looks like pycryptodome includes a reputable expandable-output hash function: “[Are there any variable length hash functions available for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54547634/1874170)”

Comment: Why do you need such heavy stuff? Start with a random n-bit that has h hamming weight then shuffle randomly.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude Note that I'm not posting an answer till I've got a response from the article author. The above comment is the easiest way.

Comment: @kelalaka The authors of that paper [appear to be](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/90243/8287) using "permutation" in a non-standard way; they use it _only_ to mean a bijection between all $n$-bit strings, and not a bijection between $n$-bit strings sharing hamming weight $h$... still neat, from a mathematical perspective, but not useful for this case.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I'm not sure, I've written an e-mail to them, waiting for the response. I've already provide the simplest solution on the above comment.

Comment: @‌kelalaka To be explicit: You think there's a chance that @AYun's answer is incorrect?

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude block cipher is a family of permutations. Each key fixed a permutation where the elements are 128-bit strings. Is this what you miss?

Comment: @‌XuguiManuel If you finish and publish your toy implementation, could you drop a link in the comments? I'm interested to see how it works out. (@kelalaka the issue was, the paper OP was reading used "random permutation" in the [common sense: a random *ordering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation); whereas that paper I mistakenly thought applied used it as a fancy word for "bijection"...)

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude: The mathematical term *permutation* (a bijection, i.e., invertible mapping, between any two sets of the same cardinality) is more general than the historical crypto term *permutation* which usually means a bit permutation or bit shuffle. Compare this second use with *substitution* which in crypto usually means an Sbox mapping which is a *nonlinear permutation.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember: a [random permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation) (or, when taken bitwise, "a hamming-weight-preserving one-way function") is known in layman's terms as a **shuffle**.

There are [well-known correct algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) to do this — Python itself, for example, makes it quite convenient to just leverage [its `shuffle` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.5/Lib/random.py#L349-L373) by subclassing `Random` with your choice of [DRBG](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/35007/8287):

```
from random import Random
from resource import getpagesize as _getpagesize
from functools import reduce as _reduce
from itertools import islice as _islice, repeat as _repeat

from Cryptodome.Hash import SHAKE256


def deterministic_shuffle(seq, seed, sponge=SHAKE256):
    """Applies a pseudorandom permutation from arbitrary bytestring `seed` to mutable sequence `seq`, using SHAKE256 as the DRBG."""
    stream = sponge.new(data=seed)
    random = StreamBasedRandom(stream=stream, blocksize=136)
    random.shuffle(seq)


class StreamBasedRandom(Random):
    def __init__(self, stream, blocksize=_getpagesize()):
        self._randbitgen = _ibytestobits(map(stream.read, _repeat(blocksize)))
    def getrandbits(self, k):
        return _concatbits(_islice(self._randbitgen, k))
    # Fix the following functions to prevent implementation-dependency
    def randbytes(self, n):
        return self.getrandbits(n * 8).to_bytes(n, 'big')
    def _randbelow(self, n):
        """Replacement for CPython's Random._randbelow that wastes very few bits"""
        if n <= 1:
            return 0
        getrandbits = self.getrandbits
        k = (n - 1).bit_length()
        a = getrandbits(k)
        b = 2 ** k
        if n == b:
            return a
        while (n * a // b) != (n * (a + 1) // b):
            a = a * 2 | getrandbits(1)
            b *= 2
        return n * a // b
    def shuffle(self, x):
        """Modern Fisher-Yates shuffle"""
        randbelow = self._randbelow
        for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):
            j = randbelow(i + 1)
            x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]


def _ibytestobits(ibytes):
    """Turns an iterator of bytes into an iterator of its component bits, big-endian"""
    yield from ((i >> k) & 0b1 for b in ibytes for i in b for k in reversed(range(8)))

def _concatbits(bits):
    """Takes a finite iterator of bits and returns their big-endian concatenation as an integer"""
    return _reduce((lambda acc, cur: ((acc << 1) | cur)), bits, 0)
```

([SHAKE256](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/stable/src/hash/shake256.html) was used in this example code; it should be easily repurposeable to any bit generator. See [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/39543/8287) for some other ideas, and the appendix to this answer for a concrete example of how that might be done.)

To use this in your code would be *something like* this:

```
k = b'Hyper Secret Input Key'
h = len(k) * 8
n = 4096
assert n > (8 * h)

# An n-element bit sequence of hamming weight h
bitstream = ([1] * h) + ([0] * (n - h))
deterministic_shuffle(bitstream, k)

print("Shuffled bitstream:", _concatbits(bitstream).to_bytes(n // 8, 'big').hex())
```

---

Appendix: example usage of another DRBG

```
# this block of code depends on StreamBasedRandom, defined above
from types import SimpleNamespace as _SimpleNamespace

from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Hash import SHA256


def deterministic_shuffle(seq, seed, nonce=b''):
    """Applies a pseudorandom permutation from 256-bit (32-byte) `seed` to mutable sequence `seq`, using AES-256-CTR as the DRBG."""
    assert len(seed) == 32, "seed must be 256 bits (32 bytes) long for AES-256."
    cipher = AES.new(key=seed, mode=AES.MODE_CTR, nonce=nonce)
    def randbytes(n):
        return cipher.encrypt(b'\x00' * n)
    stream = _SimpleNamespace(read=randbytes)
    random = StreamBasedRandom(stream=stream, blocksize=cipher.block_size)
    random.shuffle(seq)

def _normalize(data):
    return SHA256.new(data).digest()

k = b'Hyper Secret Input Key'
h = len(k) * 8
n = 4096
assert n > (8 * h)

bitstream = ([1] * h) + ([0] * (n - h))
deterministic_shuffle(bitstream, _normalize(k))

print("AES-shuffled bitstream:", _concatbits(bitstream).to_bytes(n // 8, 'big').hex())
```

Comment: Interestingly, [according to some dude on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-better-shuffling-algorithms-than-Fisher%E2%80%93Yates-shuffle/answer/James-Lintern), Fisher-Yates ([which Python uses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371105/1874170)) is "optimal" -- his description of *why* seems underwhelming, but I don't doubt it per se...

Comment: (Admittedly, with the key functions fixed thus, I suppose it doesn't actually *need* to subclass `Random`…)