# How does this generate a permutation?

Tags: implementation, permutation, pseudo-random-permutation, notation

In the process of trying to answer [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/90156/8287), I ended up getting stuck. I found a paper which seems to solve their issue: its authors define a process which yields a [pseudorandom permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation) generator $h$ when applied to a pseudorandom function $f$ and the resulting $g$ composed twice onto itself:

> Let $f=\{f\}^n$ be a pseudorandom function generator where the key length function is $l(n)$. Define a function generator $g=\{g\}^n$ in terms of $f$ as follows. Let $k$ be a string of length $l(n)$, let $k'$ be a string of length $l(n+1)$, let $L$, $R$, and $L'$ be strings of length $n$, and let $R$ be a string of length $n+1$. Then $$g_{k}^{2n}(L\bullet R)=R\bullet[L\oplus f_k^n(R)]$$ $$g_{k'}^{2n+1}=R'\bullet[L'\oplus\text{first }n\text{ bits of }f_{k'}^{n+1}(R')]$$
>
> …
>
> Let $h=g\circ g\circ g$. … Theorem 1 shows that $h$ is pseudorandom if $f$ is pseudorandom… [however, note that] $h=g\circ g$ is not at all pseudorandom[.]

– [Michael Luby](http://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/icsi/people/luby) and [Charles Rackoff](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Erackoff/), [How to construct pseudorandom permutations from pseudorandom functions](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs276/fa20/notes/Luby_Rackoff_paper.pdf).

However, as I'm implementing it, it *seems* not to be actually yielding a rearrangement of the input bits. I'll show an example where I provide an input with a hamming weight of 4, but it returns a string with a hamming weight of 15 -- so, clearly not a permutation of the input.

- Parameters:

  - $f$ = [SHAKE256](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/hash/shake256.html)
  - $m = 00001000\ 00000100\ 00000010\ 00000001$
  - $n = 32$
  - $l(n) = 0 \Rightarrow k = \text{‘’}$

So, going through it step-by-step:

1. $g_{k}^{n}(g_{k}^{n}(g_{k}^{n}(m)))$
2. $g_{k}^{n}(g_{k}^{n}(g_{k}^{n}(00001000\ 00000100\bullet 00000010\ 00000001)))$
3. $g_{k}^{n}(g_{k}^{n}(00000010\ 00000001\bullet[00001000\ 00000100\oplus f_k^{n/2}(00000010\ 00000001)]))$

   - Python: `Crypto.Hash.SHAKE256.new(k).update(b'\x02\x01').read( (n//2) // 8 )`
4. $g_{k}^{n}(g_{k}^{n}(00000010\ 00000001\bullet[00001000\ 00000100\oplus 10111101\ 00000101]))$
5. $g_{k}^{n}(g_{k}^{n}(00000010\ 00000001\bullet 10110101\ 00000001))$
6. $g_{k}^{n}(10110101\ 00000001\bullet[00000010\ 00000001\oplus f_k^{n/2}(10110101\ 00000001)])$

   - Python: `Crypto.Hash.SHAKE256.new(k).update(b'\xb5\x01').read( (n//2) // 8 )`
7. $g_{k}^{n}(10110101\ 00000001\bullet[00000010\ 00000001\oplus 10100111\ 01010000])$
8. $g_{k}^{n}(10110101\ 00000001\bullet 10100101\ 01010001)$
9. $10100101\ 01010001\bullet[10110101\ 00000001\oplus f_k^{n/2}(10100101\ 01010001)]$

   - Python: `Crypto.Hash.SHAKE256.new(k).update(b'\xa5\x51').read( (n//2) // 8 )`
10. $10100101\ 01010001\bullet [10110101\ 00000001\oplus 10000010\ 01010011]$
11. $10100101\ 01010001\ 00110111\ 01010010$

Since this has not yielded a permutation of $m$, how do the authors actually intend this composition to be done? Am I misinterpreting $\bullet$? Am I botching the composition? Should I be splitting $m$ differently? I did not see any special requirements on $f$ other than it be able to output $n$ bits (and even that looked non-strict, being croppable when an odd number of bits is required), so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a permutation not in the sense that it permutes the bit positions of the given input, but in the sense that it is a one-to-one correspondence from a set (of bitstrings) to the same set, as defined in that paper:

> **2. Terminology** …
>
> Let $F^n$ be the set of all ${2^n}^{2^n}$ functions mapping
> $\{0,1\}^n$ into $\{0,1\}^n$… Let $P^n\subset F^n$ be the set of such
> functions that are permutations, i.e., they are 1-1 onto functions.

Comment: Darn! So they really just mean “A bijective $f: \{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}^n$”? 
(I could have avoided so much effort if I'd checked somewhere other than Wikipedia for definitions…)

Comment: So, I wasn't just crazy… it looks like _some_ papers use "permutation" in the common-language sense: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/801.pdf#:~:text=applying%20a%20permutation,does%20not%20change%20the%20hamming%20weight https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.24.1615&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Bijection and permutation are often used interchangeably.